# ASP.NET (MVC) application with Session State on an Azure SQL Server Database (same as app's)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, session-state

I read (and tried) everything I found about this goal, but I still cannot handle it...

I found I have to run this script:

aspnet_regsqlazure.exe -ssadd -d  -sstype c -S  -U  -P

after having downloaded the executable, but it says that:

Install Session State is not supported by aspnet_regsqlazure

...and this is only the last step I tried: when I could create (any?) tables in the database, then it always says that:

Unable to use SQL Server because either ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server, or ASP.NET does not have...

Is there anyone that can point me to the right (and updated!) infos on this subject?

Thanks in advance.

AB

Comment: I reckon you would be most like be better using Caching for session state http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx Best would be not to use Session at all.

Comment: Yes, I can agree that this should be better: but using Session is easy, while for Caching I have to study a lot of things, experimenting, and so on... I would like to solve this problem, now, and then, with time, study all the rest!

Comment: You should be able to use Azure Caching for session and it will be no harder, probably easier, than using SQL Server for Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Redis cache, it's significantly faster, easier to set up and cheaper. See the Azure Redis Cache (Preview) ASP.NET Session State Provider section of [MVC movie app with Azure Redis Cache in 15 minutes](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/05/mvc-movie-app-with-azure-redis-cache-in-15-minutes/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers) you don't need to create the session tables upfront; it will be done automatically using EF Migrations when your app starts up.

Comment: I thought this, too, but when I run the application I get back the error I wrote before, that I write here complete, even if I get back it in italian, and I translated it with google:

Comment: Unable to use SQL Server because ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server or do not have permission to run the stored procedure dbo.TempGetVersion. If the schema ASP.NET session state has not been installed, install the ASP.NET session state SQL Server version 2.0 or later. If the schema was installed, grant execute permission on the stored procedure dbo.TempGetVersion identity of the application pool ASP.NET SQL Server or the user specified in the sqlConnectionString.

Comment: Obvious question, but does the SQL user you are using to connect from your Azure app have the necessary permissions (e.g. to create tables)?

Comment: Now I'm not so sure anymore... I created the database (quick create) assigning an initial username and password, and I'm using those... aren't the administrator (god :-)) credentials?